# SQLite Android Database Preloading Database and Management

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I currently have a database that's going to be updated via the internet. However, I am also going to have a preloaded database to start the users off. I was figuring out what would be the best way to do the preloaded information while allowing updates based on a database version number. So I might include a database resource file or add them all using a LIST. So my question is, how should I manage my starting off database and make sure it isn't adding the tables over and over again, should I use this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper or maybe a shared preferences using the Database version or something?

Comment: so you have two databases, one pre loaded the other which is being updated from the internet am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Add the database file(with pre-loaded data) to the assets folder of your project.
Then when the database is called in the application,check whether the database exists and if it doesn't, copy the database from the assets to your application

I think a good example to do this with sample code exists in a blog. Just google around and you should find it

Answer (score 0):

Your content provider will call

```
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
```

which will call `onCreate` and `OnUpgrade` of the sqlite openhelper if needed.  So I don't see any need to use an extra library to do this.  You'll be out in the cold the first time you have to upgrade your app.  I think is the best way to upgrade a SQLite database is and I call it the Adams Upgrade method for the [blog](http://blog.adamsbros.org/2012/02/28/upgrade-android-sqlite-database/) I found it on.

Here's what I have in the onUpgrade method.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

```
    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int res;
        switch (upgradeTo) {
        // update old resrawid's to constants
        // this was caused when I saved R values in the database
        // and then later realized they would change.
        // the old resrawid is changed to a constant.
        case 42:
            ContentValues values;
            int rs;
            rs = 2130968576;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_DRAGON);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });

            rs = 2130968577;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_M119);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });

            rs = 2130968578;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_MEDINA);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });
            break;
        case 43:
            // new column added for last_viewed.
            db.execSQL(VERSION_43_ALTER);
            break;

        case 44:
            // new index on KEY_DATE_UPDATE DESC
            db.execSQL(VERSION_44_CREATE_INDEX);
            break;
        case 45:
            // change field name id to _id
            // check if current table has _id column
            String s = "PRAGMA table_info(" + TABLE_RIDES + ")";
            Cursor ti = db.rawQuery(s, null);
            if (ti.moveToFirst()) {
                String key = ti.getString(1);
                if (!key.equals(KEY_ID)) {
                    // drop existing indexes
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_DROP_INDEX);
                    // rename old table
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_RENAME_TABLE);
                    // create new table
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_CREATE_TABLE);
                    // copy from old table to new table
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_COPY_TABLE);
                    // delete old table
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_DROP_TEMP_TABLE);
                    // CREATE DROPED INDEXES
                    db.execSQL(VERSION_45_CREATE_INDEX);
                }
            }
            // get the row count if zero then add in the samples
            long x = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_RIDES);
            if (x == 0) {
                loaddatabase(db);
            }
        }
        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```

Why not just make insert statements for the preload data and then execute them on the device.  You will be guaranteed it work on every device.

Comment: Should I use a Application patch file to update the database or should I use something with my server such as JavaScript.

Comment: No you should have a sql script to populate your database.  A text file in raw folder that will compress up nicely.